# glossaries protect whitespace between text and abbrevation

Tags: spacing, glossaries, acronyms

I'm using the glossaries package for a list of abbreviations. I have a problem when I use the command `\gls` with an abbreviation for the first time if it's near the end of a line.

So e.g. the abbreviation `Data-Mining (DM)` will end up as `Data-Mining` in the first line and `(DM)` in the second line. I would like to set a protected whitespace between `Data-Mining` and `(DM)`. I tried `\mbox`, but in this case I just get an overfull hbox, because the text is printed in one line. The best break point would be the hyphen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would help if you could provide a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) but since you haven't, I'll assume you're doing something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{dm}{DM}{Data-Mining}

\begin{document}

\rule{0.8\textwidth}{1pt}\gls{dm}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces the undesired line break:

[image: Line break between Data-Mining and (DM)]

In this case the fix is quite straight-forward. You just need to replace the `long-short` acronym style with the `long-sp-short` style. Like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\setacronymstyle{long-sp-short}
\newacronym{dm}{DM}{Data-Mining}

\begin{document}

\rule{0.8\textwidth}{1pt}\gls{dm}.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This now produces:

[image: No line break]

This style uses `\glsacspace{label}` between the long and short form. This command defaults to using `~` if `(\firstacronymfont{\glsentryshort{label}})` is less than 3em, otherwise it uses `\space`. You can redefine it to always use a non-breakable space:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsacspace}[1]{~}
```

Comment: Thank you it was the right assumption. Next time I use a MWE or just find the answer within your manual ;)

Comment: @user2653422 That's all right. The answer got me past the 15k rep mark :-)